# Can I create a online game using meteor like slither.io?

Tags: meteor, online-game

I'm wondering about meteor reactivity and I have an idea about one online game like slither.io.

Can I create online game because meteor *optimistic UI* offers simpliest way to update data without reloading the page.

Does it possible ?

---

Sorry for stupid question I'm relatively new about Meteor.

Comment: Yep. Answer so short I had to add this sentence to meet minimum requirements.

Comment: In reply to your message.
I'm glad to know that's possible.
Thank you ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my experience with Meteor.

- For prototyping then demo to someone, then "YES"
- For going to production with millions of users playing at the same time + minimum network delay + high performance, then "NO" (or we need to do some secret workaround to gain more performance)

Btw, Slither.io front-end is mainly using HTML5 canvas, so using Meteor with a lot of built-in libraries for front-end (Blaze, MiniMongo, ...) is not a good idea.

IMHO, nodejs on back-end, websocket / socketio ft. HTML5 canvas are enough.

Comment: I created simple one, please take a look at the [picture](https://s31.postimg.org/rbt0dogjv/image.png).

I just wanted to notice you're right.
It's become unbearable to play if there more than 10 peoples.
I'm believe that meteor still good tool for building website but not for games.

Thank you guy!!!

Comment: Are you sure? Node js can be used to create ios , android game?